# Создание новых переменных

Tags: python, tkinter, переменные, label, данные

Господа, помогите с выбором направления, для решения проблемы...
Делаю программу через библиотеку `tkinter` и есть замысел, чтобы пользователь мог заполнить форму после заполнения которой -  создавались новые переменные отображающие через виджеты внесённые данные в главном окне. Проблема в том, что пользователь может создать много таких виджетов и все они должны быть отображены.

```
label = ttk.Label(text=f'{Name.get()}')
label.pack()
ttk.Progressbar(orient="horizontal", length=150, value=f'{Step.get()}').pack(pady=5)
```

Через пресловутый `format` добавляются в виджет необходимые значения пользователя. Однако, как их сохранить и отображать, если это делается не один раз!?
Я подумал о постоянном создании уникальных переменных, но потом понял, что если я думаю о такой ерунде, значит делаю, что-то не правильно, верно? Если так, то как сделать правильно? Я ума не приложу, как после ввода данных пользователем СОЗДАВАТЬ новую переменную, ведь именно она будет распаковываться в программе выводя данные....

Comment: Используйте списки или словари вместо создания новых переменных

Comment: Если вам нужно, что бы после ввода пользователем информации один раз (вроде регистрации), она потом отображалась в основном окне, то просто используйте текстовый файл, как сохранение информации, и уже из него подгружайте нужное в приложение. Честно говоря - очень смутно понимаю в чём ваша проблема.

Comment: Если пользователь может создавать бесконечное количество виджетов (что-то вроде стикеров с текстом), то соглашусь с @insolor, используйте словари. А для сохранения этих словарей используйте файл